# Django- filtering on ManyToMany field with exact matches

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter

I have the following models:

```
class Hashtag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)


class Annotation(models.Model):
    ...
    hashtags = models.ManyToManyField(Hashtag)
```

I want to get the Anntoations that have all `[hashtag_1, hashtag_2, hashtag_3]` as their hashtag.

Following is my query:

```
annotations = Annotation.objects.filter(
    hashtags__title__in=["hashtag_1", "hashtag_2", "hashtag_3"]
)
```

This queryset, returns all annotation that have at least one of `["hashtag_1", "hashtag_2", "hashtag_3"]` but I want to receive the annotations that have **only** these 3 hashtags (not more than and not less than these hashtags).

How can I do that?

I also tried the following query:

```
annotations = Annotation.objects.annotate(
    hashtag_count=Count("hashtags")
).filter(
    hashtags__title__in=["hashtag_1", "hashtag_2", "hashtag_3"],
    hashtag_count=3
)
```

if an annotation has `[hashtag_1, hashtag_2, hashtag_n]`, this query will return it (that is not what I want)

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db.models import Q
target_hashtags = ["hashtag_1", "hashtag_2", "hashtag_3"]
```

> Initialize a Q object for the first hashtag.

```
query = Q(hashtags__title=target_hashtags[0])
```

> Use a loop to construct the query for the remaining hashtags using logical AND.

```
for hashtag in target_hashtags[1:]:
    query &= Q(hashtags__title=hashtag)
```

> Fetch annotations that have all three hashtags.

```
annotations_with_all_hashtags = Annotation.objects.filter(query)
```

> Now annotations_with_all_hashtags contains the annotations that have all three specified hashtags.

Comment: I have tested it before and it didn't return the correct result. By the way, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Annotation.objects.filter(
    hashtags__title="hashtag_1"
).filter(
    hashtags__title="hashtag_2"
).filter(
    hashtags__title="hashtag_3"
)
```